# Problema inserir dados php mysql ID

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um problema em inserir dados no mysql devido ao id da tabela.

Tb_Detalhe_Trabalhador: id, Nome, Funcao

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO tb_detalhe_trabalhador VALUES ('','".$Nome1."','".$Funcao1."')
```

> Erro:  Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Será que tenho de por os campos do mysql depois do nome da tabela?

Comment: e ai funcionou a solução para você?

Comment: Ja consegui arranjar outro erro kkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correto:

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO tb_detalhe_trabalhador(nome, funcao) VALUES ('".$Nome1."','".$Funcao1."')";
```

Quando tem um campo `auto_increment`, no insert não precisa informá-lo, mas, os campos obrigatórios devem ser indicados. Esse *insert* que eu te mostrei é uma boa prática, nunca deixe de passar os campos.

Comment: O Id não aparece?

Comment: O seu Id estou julgando que é `auto_increment`, porque, você passou ''.

Comment: Sim o Id é auto_increment.. Mas como indicou continua aparecendo o mesmo erro

Comment: Mostra a estrutura da sua tabela.

Comment: é mostre a estrutura !!! @user3253195